# OpenGl world using camera to find object

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, 360-degrees

I am trying to create a virtual 360 degree world using the device as the center, i then want a simple shape to move around randomly in this world. The user is then supposed to use the camera to try and find the object moving around. i can make a simple shape in opengl, but have no idea how to make move around in a virtual world off screen. as well as how to use the camera to find. An tips or ways to simplify the problem?

Comment: Bind your scene camera to the device's gyro. Set the Scene camera inside a cube, sphere, etc and then just create an object inside those bounds (let's say another cube). Let it move random on all 3 axis and check on each move if it's still within the bounds of your bigger cube. This should give you a simple example.

Comment: If you don't know how to move objects in your scene, you should definitely check out [transformations](https://open.gl/transformations).