# Move an image based on phone movement (ROTATION_VECTOR)

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm very new to working with the sensors on an Android device. I have the following code (which I obtained from various tutorials).

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)
    {
        float[] orientationVals = new float[3];
        // Convert the rotation-vector to a 4x4 matrix.
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix,
                event.values);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);

        orientationVals[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[0]);
        orientationVals[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[1]);
        orientationVals[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[2]);

        txtAzimuth.setText("Azimuth : "+d.format(orientationVals[0]) + '°');
        txtPitch.setText("Pitch : "+d.format(orientationVals[1]) + '°');
        txtRoll.setText("Roll : "+d.format(orientationVals[2]) + '°');
    }

}
```

Okay, so I've got these values. How do I use them to move an image (a marker of sorts) based on the movement of the phone. For example, if I move the phone to the right, the image should move to the left and when the phone is moved left later, the image should move right.

I've done a lot of googling and what I've found is mostly OpenGl stuff.

Like this:

[OpenGl world using camera to find object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120519/opengl-world-using-camera-to-find-object)

This question asks what I want with the exception of the object moving randomly. I want the object position to be decided by me.

I don't want to use OpenGL for this as it would be overkill for my app. Could I somehow map the values produced by the sensors to moving the image?